# swift class property behavior

Tags: swift, properties, constants

I appreciate your help in figuring out what happens with the property in this class.

```
class CustomCorner: MDCCornerTreatment{
    var radius: CGFloat = 12;

    convenience init(radius: CGFloat) {
        self.init();
        self.radius = radius;
        print("Corner initialized with radius=\(self.radius)");
    }

    override func pathGeneratorForCorner(withAngle angle: CGFloat) -> MDCPathGenerator {
        print("entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius \(self.radius)")
        
        let path = MDCPathGenerator(start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: radius))
        print("continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius \(radius)")
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: radius, y: radius))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: radius, y: 0))
        return path
    }
}
```

when used with this code:

```
    let mdcRectangleShape = MDCRectangleShapeGenerator()
    let customCorner = CustomCorner(radius: 8)
    
    print("step 1 radio=\(customCorner.radius)")
    customCorner.radius = 5
    
    print("step 2 radio=\(customCorner.radius)")
    mdcRectangleShape.setCorners(customCorner)
    
    print("step 3 radio=\(customCorner.radius)")
    let _ = customCorner.pathGeneratorForCorner(withAngle: 10)
    nextButton.shapeGenerator = mdcRectangleShape
    
    print("step 4 radio=\(customCorner.radius)")
```

I get the following output:

> Corner initialized with radius=8.0
> step 1 radio=8.0
> step 2 radio=5.0
> step 3 radio=5.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 5.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 5.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> step 4 radio=5.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
> continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0

Here I'm using Material Design Components for iOS, although the problem seems more like a Swift problem.
This is my debug code, I have intentionally inserted different values to show the problem.
No matter how I set the radius property, once it is used inside the overriden function pathGeneratorForCorner:withAngle, it uses only the first value assigned.
What looks like to me, is that somewhere there is an environment capture, although it is not a closure since it is an overriden function. (Can functions capture environments? If so, how do I avoid it?)
What I have done so far to no avail:

- Wrapped the value inside a Class. I know it is redundant since CGFloat is already a class, but it was a wild shot.
- After step 1, I assigned the value directly. It is changed, as step 2 shows, but inside the function, the value used is the first value assigned, 12
- What I thought would be a killer, I created an UnsafePointer inside the function pointing to the property, and to my surprise, it retained the first value (as if the property had a second memory, which it doesn't)
- I tried to use a constant (let), but it got all messed up with the convenience initializer asking to call itself, and then a designated initializer came in, only to complain that it was calling an undefined init, and all sort of problems, among them, the order to call the init and the property being initialized. If it sounds messy, it was.
- I also tried an optional value, but it didn't work either.

I really appreciate your help.
Regards.
Alfredo.

Comment: "CGFloat is already a class" no it's not

Comment: Seems approrpriate to have the radius be a `let` constant. You should figure out how initializers work and sort that out.

Comment: Anyway, I wrapped it in a class, so it should've kept a reference, but it didn't

Comment: I don't know what `it` is in your statement

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica You don't think `customCorner.radius = 5` is an assignment to `radius`?

Comment: @matt Ah, missed it.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I'll say it more clearly: "I wrapped the property in a class, so the function should have kept the reference to the object but the function didn't keep a reference" to the object that contained the CGFloat, rather it kept the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already menthioned in matt's answer, what are showing `entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0` are the copies of your `customCorner`.

From the [GitHub of Material iOS](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/components/Shapes/src/MDCRectangleShapeGenerator.m), `[MDCRectangleShapeGenerator setCorners:]` is implemented as follows:

```
- (void)setCorners:(MDCCornerTreatment *)cornerShape {
  self.topLeftCorner = [cornerShape copy];
  self.topRightCorner = [cornerShape copy];
  self.bottomRightCorner = [cornerShape copy];
  self.bottomLeftCorner = [cornerShape copy];
}
```

In fact, it make 4 copies of the object given to `setCorners:`.

Your `CustomCorner` inherits `MDCCornerTreatment` which conforms to `NSCopying`.
`MDCCornerTreatment` implements `copyWithZone:` which is needed to conform to `NSCopying`, but the implementation does not know the properties of its subclasses.

You may need to modify this default copying behavior by overriding `copy(with:)` in your `CustomCorner`.

```
class CustomCorner: MDCCornerTreatment{
    var radius: CGFloat = 12;

    convenience init(radius: CGFloat) {
        self.init();
        self.radius = radius;
        print("Corner initialized with radius=\(self.radius)");
    }
    
    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let newCopy = super.copy(with: zone) as! CustomCorner
        newCopy.radius = self.radius
        return newCopy
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes. You are right, and so are matt and Alexander - Reinstate Monica. I'm accepting your answer for the insight about the copy function (honestly, I skipped objectiveC and missed the call to copy). All of you were right about several objects being created. Thanks a lot to everyone. You saved my weekend,

Answer (score 0):

All modern programming is object-based programming. Here's the thing about object-based programming; there can be more than one *instance* of an object type, and each such instance maintains its *own* instance property values, individually.

So, the relationship between your code and your output is clear up to this point:

```
let mdcRectangleShape = MDCRectangleShapeGenerator()
let customCorner = CustomCorner(radius: 8)

print("step 1 radio=\(customCorner.radius)")
customCorner.radius = 5

print("step 2 radio=\(customCorner.radius)")
mdcRectangleShape.setCorners(customCorner)

print("step 3 radio=\(customCorner.radius)")
let _ = customCorner.pathGeneratorForCorner(withAngle: 10)
nextButton.shapeGenerator = mdcRectangleShape
```

Your output is:

```
Corner initialized with radius=8.0
step 1 radio=8.0
step 2 radio=5.0
step 3 radio=5.0
entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 5.0
continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 5.0
```

Yep, well, that's what we expect to see. You set the radius to `5` and it stayed `5`.

Okay, so where did all the other output come from?

```
entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0
```

Those would be from some *other* CustomCorner instances, where you did *not* set the `radius` to `5`. It's still at the default, `12`, the way you initialized it:

```
var radius: CGFloat = 12;
```

As for where those other instances are coming from, I have no idea. You didn't show enough code for me to know that.

To confirm this, just keep printing the CustomCorner object *itself*. It will print its memory address, which is a unique identifier. You will see that you have multiple *different* CustomCorner objects.

Comment: no, those are not different objects, that's for sure. Those are repetitive calls to the function pathGeneratorForCorner made, I guess, by the framework. In theory the function is called with a different parameter in :angle, although I traced it and always is pi/2. And in case it is not clear, all the lines where the radius equals 12 occur AFTER the property has been changed from that value.

Comment: Can you show a log output that shows all the same messages, but prepending `"\((ObjectIdentifier(self)) ..."`?

Comment: Programming maxim: Anytime you say "that's for sure", that usually means you're wrong. Look, if there is just one CustomCorner object, how do you explain that `entering pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0, continuing pathGeneratorForCorner with radius 12.0` prints half a dozen times between your step 3 print and your step 4 print? Never mind the value of the radius, where would all of those come from _at all?_ There's no way they can come from this one `customCorner` reference you are showing us.

Comment: @matt well, it happens that I'm working with the same code in android and it does the same thing. The function is called just as many times by the framework, the docs say that the calls are made with a different value for :angle. In both cases, the framework works the same. The only difference is what Swift does with the property. And yes, that's what is important

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica so it seems that you nailed it! :-). I just need to find the hammer tho. I did what you said (I don't know how to post here such a long message). But it seems that the framework is creating 4 objects which are used to call the function when this line: nextButton.shapeGenerator=mdcRectangleShape is executed. Each object is used in 2 rounds sequentially. However, it seems that the framework doesn't call init in creating those objects. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry but _I_ nailed it. You just didn’t listen.

Comment: you were right all this time and so was @Alexander-ReinstateMonica. I accepted OOPer answer for the reason I explained in his answer but I sincerely thank all of you for your time and knowledge in helping me. Thank you very much to everybody. You saved my weekend, on Monday :-)

Comment: Yes, OOPs answer is best. It’s the rudeness and not listening I’m referring to. I said right in my answer, “just keep printing the CustomCorner object itself. It will print its memory address, which is a unique identifier. You will see that you have multiple different CustomCorner objects”. You didn’t. Instead you told me I was wrong.